# Spock 'throw new Exception()' feature not working

Tags: spock

I am trying to make use of {throw new Exception()} in Spock, but on running the test it prints in report--

"The following problems occurred:
    Expected exception of type 'java.lang.Exception', but no exception was thrown"

```
package testing

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyFirstSpec extends Specification {
    def "Test_One" (){

                given:              
                    def obj = new SpockMethodsPlaceholder()
                    obj.returnAge(0) >> {throw new Exception("invalidAge")}
                when:
                    1*obj.returnAge(0)
                then:
                    Exception ex = thrown()
                    ex.getMessage() == "invalidAge"

            }

        class SpockMethodsPlaceholder {
            def "returnAge" (int age){
                return age
            }
        }   
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Below is the stack trace of test run---

Working Directory: 
Gradle User Home: /home/mafia/.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 4.3
Java Home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Tests: testing.MyFirstSpec

:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava
:compileTestGroovy
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses
:test

testing.MyFirstSpec > Test_One FAILED
    org.spockframework.runtime.WrongExceptionThrownError at MyFirstSpec.groovy:16

1 test completed, 1 failed
There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///media/mafia/A08200E98200C62E/Study/Git_Repo/GIT_JAVA/workbench/SpockProject/build/reports/tests/test/index.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 19s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstand the concept of stubbing/mocking

What exactly is tested? Class `SpockMethodPlaceholder`? In this case it should not be mocked/ stubbed its a "class-under-test" - the code that you check and want to gain a confidence that it works (the code in the methods of this class if you wish)

On the other hand, if you use `>>` syntax you probably do intend to Stub something.

So here is a better example:

```
public class SomeClass {
   public int return getAge(int age) {
     if(age <= 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("too young");
     } else {
       return age;
     }
   }
}


class SomeClassTest extends Specification {

  def "an exception is thrown if the person is too young" () {
     given:
       def subject = new SomeClass()
     when:
        subject.getAge(-1)
     then:
        def ex = thrown(IllegalArgumentException)
        ex.message == "too young" 
  }
}
```